# Android voting app nodes deleting when firebase node is empty

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm designing a voting app. When the user submits a vote their user id is stored under the relevant node in the firestore database. And if a user decides to change their vote their original vote is removed (meaning their user id is removed) and saved under the node of their new vote option. Essentially this is overwriting their vote.

The problem I'm having is that if a poll option has only has one vote and this is removed due to the user changing their original vote, the node is deleted and the option is completely removed from the list. I'll illustrate below.

If you look below you'll see that Budapest and Amsterdam originally have 1 vote each. If my original vote was Budapest and I decided to change this to Krakow, my user id is removed from the Budapest node and added to the Krakow node and as a result Budapest is deleted and removed from the list as there are no values stored underneath it. This is also causing an index out of bounds exception.

I'm looking for a way around this where basically I can prevent poll options from being deleted due to having no votes. I hope this is clear. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us the code that causing an index out of bounds exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the database this is the expected behavior: a key only exists if there is a value under it. Once the last value under a key gets removed, that key is automatically removed too.

There is no way to change this behavior in the database, so you'll have to:

- Either deal with it in your code, by handling the absence of the data. This only works if you know the node names up front.
- Otherwise, you'll need to make sure the nodes always have value to prevent them from being deleted. This can be a simple marker value (i.e. `true`) that your code recognizes as "there are not votes", or you can have the options in a separate place as the *values* of a node, and keep the votes themselves as you have them now.